# Exercises for Calculus and Analysis for Graduate School Entrance Exam for Tokyo and Taiwan University

Tags: calculus, analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, advice

Can anyone recommend exercise books for the following topic? I am applying for entrance exam to a few places in Taiwan and Japan for graduate studies in maths, statistics and data sciences, as their handling of a certain pandemic is decent and their tuition fee is amazing compared to the west.

This is a link to their 2020 exam. https://www.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/common/file/edu/course/mi/2020suuri-e.pdf
https://www.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/common/file/edu/course/mi/2020suuri-e.pdf

Calculus ( single and multivariate) - includes series progressions and integrals, again some of their past year calculus has crazy sum of series ( did schaum's outline on calculus and advance calculus but then it doesn't seems enough, i need more practices for those series summation and multi integral. A link of their sample questions would be here ( https://mixedmoss.com/originmath/Emath.html) Please recommend exercise books on these.

Analysis ( Single, functional and complex) ( I did baby rudin but some questions in asian exams are non trivial) I would be working on rudin for analysis, erwin kreyzig for functional analysis, schaum outline for complex analysis ( some recommended ahlfors for the proofs, would it be enough? I think it is too much.)

Thanks in advance.